# Check if the phone has updated version of app or same version

Tags: android

How can I check if app was updated in my phone. I want to compare the current version and previous version of app.

Answer (score 0):

store the latest version number in some server and get it inside app , check with your current version 
like this

```
int versionCode = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionCode;
```

and now compare both

Answer (score 0):

Go to *Preferences* and you can find all installed apps in the point *Apps*. Select the right app and you can see which version is currently installed. Note that this is just an indication and that developers are able to update their apps without increasing the for user visible application version.